# get_comment_author_link not working properly

Tags: comments, users, author, links, author-template

I have this snippet:

```
<span><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/writer/<?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?>"><?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?></a></span>
```

I am displaying the username of the author but it's weird because it works well on the posts... Beneath the post, the username is linked like `/writer/username`, which is fine, but beneath the comment, the username is linked like `/writer/Username`. So for example, a user is called Blackboy 3 , than beneath the post it gets `/writer/blackboy-3`, beneath the comment it gets `/writer/Blackboy 3`. This makes a problem... Because if there is a post called `Blackboy 3`, than the link beneath the comment gets me to the post instead of the `author page`.

Why is this? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution drop this in your `functions.php`

```
function your_get_comment_author_link () {
    global $comment;

    if ($comment->user_id == '0') {
        if (!empty ($comment->comment_author_url)) {
            $url = $comment->comment_author_url;
        } else {
            $url = '#';
        }
    } else {
        $url = get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id);
    }

    echo "<a href=\"" . $url . "\">" .get_comment_author () . "</a>";
}
```

If the user is registered this will link to `/writer/username`, if they are not it will either link to their url or to `#` if they haven't provided one.

Obviously to use it you'll want use it in your code using

```
<span><?php your_get_comment_author_link() ?></span>
```

Taken from Johan suggestion in comments.

Comment: Yes, but it should link to the author page, right? What links there? How should I make it work?

Comment: I just updated the post with that it will link to the /writer/username unless the user provided a different URL when they commented if you allow public comments. I believe for registered users it will always link to /writer/username.

Comment: That's incorrect. There is no anchor that will link. It just displays the author name... If I put in an anchor, it just makes it the same. `Blackboy 2` instead of `blackboy-2`

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L147 should definitely have the anchor if a URL is available.

Comment: Weird, but it's showing the wrong one again... In posts it's working perfect, in comments not... Very frustrating this.

Comment: Might be something in my theme doing it I just changed it and if the URL isn't set on the comment it dosen't link to anything.

Comment: Weird. What about using something like `get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id)` ? There must be a way to link to the author page in a way if it's the comment author link

Comment: You are saying it on your answer: it will return the username, so without sanitizing it with `-` if there are spaces in the nickname. If the user has no spaces in the name, it works fine, but if it has, than not... So the `get_comment_author_link` must be wrong.

Comment: No problem full credit to @Johan for the suggestion.

Comment: I do wonder: how effective is this from a performance point of view?